# Issue with hiding a Modal - Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I cannot get a modal to hide after confirming a delete (closing works fine), thus I am trying to reference it by a modal ID now.

From what I am reading, the typical way to hide a modal is `$('#myModal').modal('hide');` 
However this does not seem to be working for me, I used `$('.modal').modal('hide');`  and I am wondering if it is because I need to specify the ID `#` of the modal, but I am not sure what the "correct" way of doing that is if my ID is an `@model` attribute`

Here is my button

```
<button class="btn btn-danger col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@item.ID" onclick="deleteStart(this)">
```

Here is my initial div class for my modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="@item.ID" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Here is my JQuery that is the `onClick` for my Confirm Delete option(I have a few attempts within the code)

```
function deleteFunction(element) {
var newID = $(element).closest("td").find("span.ID").text();

$.post(
'@Url.Action("customDelete", "Show")',
{
    'id': newID
},
function (data) { },
"json"
);
        $(element).closest("tr").next("tr").remove();
        $(element).closest("tr").remove();

        //$(element).attr("data-target", "#" + newID).modal('hide');
        //$('#newID').modal('hide');
        //$('.modal').modal('hide');

        $(element).closest("table").toggleClass("table-hover");
        $(element).closest("tr").css('background-color', 'initial');
    }
```

NOTE: the `var newID` applies to the current item's object ID (`item.ID`), but since that is what my modal ID is set to as well, shouldn't it be working?

*`item.ID` is my model's primary key so it is unique too*.

Comment: you can programmatically click its close button

Comment: the close button works fine, the confirm button launches this query and it does not seem to work. How would I do it within the button itself? (new to Modals)

Comment: in jquery ui modal there is close button which is anchor tag i used to click it programmatically to close the modal

Comment: Is jquery UI an add-on, or is it already part of MVC5/Bootstrap 3? I am trying to stick with just MVC5 and Bootstrap 3 default items.

Comment: it is part of bootstrap as well i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! The culprit was modal's `fade`.

In order to get this to work I had to use the following within a function that was called by the Confirm button. This has to be done BEFORE anything else, especially AJAX. Apparently AJAX can mess up some of the scripting for Modal's so you gotta finish all your modal stuff before you do other things.

**Function Snippet**

```
$('#myModal').removeClass('fade');
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

Comment: I solved it doing `$('#myModal').modal('show');` and then `$('#myModal').modal('hide');` but I really wonder what's happening here ??